# print a line after a matching word

Tags: python-2.7

I have a huge text file. I am trying to print a line after every time I find a specific word.

Example:

```
lines = 
"""
match_string
line2_0
somelines
...
...
....
match_string
line_0
...
...
...
match_string
line3_0
.
.
.
.
."""
```

My script should find "match_string" and print the first line comes after it.

line2_0

line_0

line3_0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an iterator from the lines in the string and use `next` to print the next line when you find a match on the current line. The `for` loop will then automatically continue with the line after that.

```
iterator = iter(lines.splitlines())
for line in iterator:
    if "match_string" in line:
        print next(iterator)
```

Or reading the lines from a file:

```
with open("huge_text_file.txt") as file_iterator:
    for line in file_iterator:
        if "match_string" in line:
            print next(file_iterator)
```

Output:

```
line2_0
line_0
line3_0
```

Note that this *could* raise a `StopIteration` exception in case there is no `next` line after the line containing `match_string`. In this case, just wrap the code in a `try/except` block.

Comment: Be careful, if it is possible to have "match_string" as a last row in a file (from some strange reason) this code will raise an error. But it can be easily handled by a `try except` block or just make sure that `match_string` cannot be in the last line of the file.

Comment: How can I read lines between every two iterations? for example: if "line2_0" is what I want, I will look for another line between the two "match_string"s that "line2_0" falls between.

Comment: @Omar What exactly do you mean? Do you want to process all the lines until the next `match_string`, or until some other delimiter, like an empty line? Or just the next two lines, instead of just the next?

Comment: Lets say I want to read the number that is part of the word that comes after match_word. In my example, it is "0" in line2_0 or line_0.. etc. if this number is equal "1", then I process the lines that come after it and before the next match_string looking for another parameter.

Comment: @Omar Well, you could just add another `next(iterator)` after that, or even another `for line2 in iterator:` and `break` from that nested loop when you encounter the next match, or an empty line, or whatever.